# Can Dimple.js aggregate and group data

Tags: dimple.js

I have data that looks like this (this is fake data presented here):

```
physician|patient|location|datetime|condition|treatment|billed|collected
Deanna Smith|Marko Cruise|Tampa|20140104|diabetic retinopathy|eylea|1800|1706
Jenna Lewis|Jenna Han|Jacksonville|20150320|macular deg.|eylea|1800|1726
George Cruise|Lisa Washington|Orlando|20140509|diabetic retinopathy|ajurdec|800|740
Lisa Kozaczinski|Lana Brown|Tampa|20151012|macular deg.|avastin|400|275
Lisa Smith|Joanna Cruise|Tampa|20140921|macular deg.|lucentis|1200|1061
Mike Taylor|Lana Smith|Orlando|20150322|diabetic retinopathy|ajurdec|800|676
Joanna Taylor|Lisa Washington|Jacksonville|20140121|macular deg.|lucentis|1200|1145
Jenna Taylor|George Taylor|Tampa|20150119|macular deg.|eylea|1800|1741
Jenna Washington|George Smith|Orlando|20150402|macular deg.|eylea|1800|1659
Mark Cheng|Lisa Taylor|Pensacola|20150418|macular deg.|eylea|1800|1679
Lisa Fox|Mike Hajdukovic|Orlando|20140423|macular deg.|ajurdec|800|693
Silvia Fox|Jenna Smith|Jacksonville|20151104|macular deg.|avastin|400|289
Mike Washington|John Hajdukovic|Tampa|20151005|macular deg.|avastin|400|302
```

and I would like to present the line chart histogram grouped by monthly or weekly collections.

Can Dimple.js do this, or do I need to pre-aggregate/group data before I chart it. [Examples on the web seem to show the data properly aggregated](http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=bars_vertical).

Do I need to maybe re-format the dates?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at `dimple.axis.timeField`, `dimple.axis.dateParseFormat`, and `timePeriod`, and `timeFormat`.

https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.axis#timeField

Dimple aggregates by default based on your series and axis setup.

The default is to use sum as the aggregate method, but averages can also be used (max, min, custom).